# ImportError : no module named requests

Tags: python, python-requests, importerror

I am trying to retrieve data from a weather website using BeautifulSoup. Sample of the website:

```
<channel>
<title>2 Hour Forecast</title>
<source>Meteorological Services Singapore</source>
<description>2 Hour Forecast</description>
<item>
<title>Nowcast Table</title>
<category>Singapore Weather Conditions</category>
<forecastIssue date="18-07-2016" time="03:30 PM"/>
<validTime>3.30 pm to 5.30 pm</validTime>
<weatherForecast>
<area forecast="TL" lat="1.37500000" lon="103.83900000" name="Ang Mo Kio"/>
<area forecast="SH" lat="1.32100000" lon="103.92400000" name="Bedok"/>
<area forecast="TL" lat="1.35077200" lon="103.83900000" name="Bishan"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.30400000" lon="103.70100000" name="Boon Lay"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.35300000" lon="103.75400000" name="Bukit Batok"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.27700000" lon="103.81900000" name="Bukit Merah"/>` 
</weatherForecast>
<channel>
```

I would like to retrieve 3.30 pm to 5.30 pm which is between **validTime**

After inspecting elements from the page, I found that 3.30 pm to 5.30 pm is in the "class = Text" within the **span** element:

[sample of how the weather data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgigL.png)

Here are my codes using Python:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

r = requests.get('http://www.nea.gov.sg/api/WebAPI/?    
dataset=2hr_nowcast&keyref=781CF461BB6606AD907750DFD1D07667C6E7C5141804F45D')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "xml")
soup.find('validTime').string
```

However, when I run the codes, I got an error saying "ImportError : No module name requests"

I have already downloaded requests and placed them [in the Lib within Python27 folder on my C drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XK6D.png)

I have also checked using "pip list" to see if I have installed requests and this is what I got:

```
beautifulsoup4 <4.4.1>
httplib2 <0.9.2>
lxml <3.6.0>
pip <8.1.2>
requests <2.10.0>
...
```

As you can see requests is already downloaded on my C drive (C:\Python27\Scripts)

Why do I have the error on command prompt?

Comment: Are you certain you're using the correct Python executable when you run it? You may have installed `requests` for one version and then tried to execute the code with another.

Comment: How do I check if I'm using the correct one?

Comment: my python is in version 2.7.12!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, let me tell about some of my confusions.

In your screen shot:[in the Lib within Python27 folder on my C drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XK6D.png/).

First, the folder "ensurepip" means that it will help you to install pip, but you don't have "site-packages" directory which means pip hasn't been installed in the python version.

Second, the folder "python2" has been there. Why is it there?

Third, if you have installed "requests" with pip command "pip install requests", why do you need to copy "requests" and where your "requests" comes from?

The solution is blow.

1.uninstall your python.

2.install python 2.7.12 msi in "C:\Python27" which will help you install pip automatically.

3.check "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip*", if it doesn't exist, your installation has been wrong.

4.add "C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts" in your system env path.

5."python" in the cmd tools to check your python version is "2.7.12" or not.

6."pip install requests" in the cmd tools.

7.check "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\requests".

If all has been done correctly, you will successfully import requests.

The install link is https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2712/

Comment: Thank you, i'll give it a try :)

Comment: HI, i followed yr steps but I'm still getting the same error :/

Comment: @plzhelp.Is the folder "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\requests" there?

Comment: is there any way that I can contact you through email or something?

Comment: My email is jiahillegass@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue as follows my error as

```
>>import requests
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#175>", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named 'requests' "
```

Download requests repository 
https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests

copy requests directory to python path [ex. C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32]